No default export found in imported module "next/dist/build". import/default
I'm building an e-commerce site using Next.js and Payload CMS with TypeScript. Everything runs fine on my local environment (localhost:3000), but when I try to deploy or build, I get the following error:
./src/server.ts

Error: No default export found in imported module "next/dist/build".  import/default

I initially thought it was a TypeScript issue but couldn't resolve it. Below are the relevant files:
server.ts
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import next from 'next';
import nextBuild from 'next/dist/build';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config({
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env'),
});

import express from 'express';
import payload from 'payload';

import { seed } from './payload/seed';

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const start = async (): Promise<void> => {
  await payload.init({
    secret: process.env.PAYLOAD_SECRET || '',
    express: app,
    onInit: () => {
      payload.logger.info(`Payload Admin URL: ${payload.getAdminURL()}`);
    },
  });

  if (process.env.PAYLOAD_SEED === 'true') {
    await seed(payload);
    process.exit();
  }

  if (process.env.NEXT_BUILD) {
    app.listen(PORT, async () => {
      payload.logger.info(`Next.js is now building...`);
      // @ts-expect-error
      await nextBuild(path.join(__dirname, '../'));
      process.exit();
    });

    return;
  }

  const nextApp = next({
    dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  });

  const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

  app.use((req, res) => nextHandler(req, res));

  nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
    payload.logger.info('Starting Next.js...');

    app.listen(PORT, async () => {
      payload.logger.info(`Next.js App URL: ${process.env.PAYLOAD_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}`);
    });
  });
};

start();

index.d.ts
import type { Revalidate } from '../server/lib/revalidate';
import '../lib/setup-exception-listeners';
import { RSC_PREFETCH_SUFFIX, RSC_SUFFIX } from '../lib/constants';
import type { Header, Redirect, Rewrite, RouteHas } from '../lib/load-custom-routes';
import type { __ApiPreviewProps } from '../server/api-utils';
import { NEXT_ROUTER_PREFETCH_HEADER, RSC_HEADER, NEXT_DID_POSTPONE_HEADER } from '../client/components/app-router-headers';
interface ExperimentalBypassForInfo {
    experimentalBypassFor?: RouteHas[];
}
interface ExperimentalPPRInfo {
    experimentalPPR: boolean | undefined;
}
interface DataRouteRouteInfo {
    dataRoute: string | null;
    prefetchDataRoute: string | null | undefined;
}
export interface SsgRoute extends ExperimentalBypassForInfo, DataRouteRouteInfo, ExperimentalPPRInfo {
    initialRevalidateSeconds: Revalidate;
    srcRoute: string | null;
    initialStatus?: number;
    initialHeaders?: Record<string, string>;
}
export interface DynamicSsgRoute extends ExperimentalBypassForInfo, DataRouteRouteInfo, ExperimentalPPRInfo {
    fallback: string | null | false;
    routeRegex: string;
    dataRouteRegex: string | null;
    prefetchDataRouteRegex: string | null | undefined;
}
export type PrerenderManifest = {
    version: 4;
    routes: {
        [route: string]: SsgRoute;
    };
    dynamicRoutes: {
        [route: string]: DynamicSsgRoute;
    };
    notFoundRoutes: string[];
    preview: __ApiPreviewProps;
};
type ManifestBuiltRoute = {
    /**
     * The route pattern used to match requests for this route.
     */
    regex: string;
};
export type ManifestRewriteRoute = ManifestBuiltRoute & Rewrite;
export type ManifestRedirectRoute = ManifestBuiltRoute & Redirect;
export type ManifestHeaderRoute = ManifestBuiltRoute & Header;
export type ManifestRoute = ManifestBuiltRoute & {
    page: string;
    namedRegex?: string;
    routeKeys?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
};
export type ManifestDataRoute = {
    page: string;
    routeKeys?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    dataRouteRegex: string;
    namedDataRouteRegex?: string;
};
export type RoutesManifest = {
    version: number;
    pages404: boolean;
    basePath: string;
    redirects: Array<Redirect>;
    rewrites?: Array<ManifestRewriteRoute> | {
        beforeFiles: Array<ManifestRewriteRoute>;
        afterFiles: Array<ManifestRewriteRoute>;
        fallback: Array<ManifestRewriteRoute>;
    };
    headers: Array<ManifestHeaderRoute>;
    staticRoutes: Array<ManifestRoute>;
    dynamicRoutes: Array<ManifestRoute>;
    dataRoutes: Array<ManifestDataRoute>;
    i18n?: {
        domains?: Array<{
            http?: true;
            domain: string;
            locales?: string[];
            defaultLocale: string;
        }>;
        locales: string[];
        defaultLocale: string;
        localeDetection?: false;
    };
    rsc: {
        header: typeof RSC_HEADER;
        didPostponeHeader: typeof NEXT_DID_POSTPONE_HEADER;
        varyHeader: string;
        prefetchHeader: typeof NEXT_ROUTER_PREFETCH_HEADER;
        suffix: typeof RSC_SUFFIX;
        prefetchSuffix: typeof RSC_PREFETCH_SUFFIX;
    };
    skipMiddlewareUrlNormalize?: boolean;
    caseSensitive?: boolean;
};
export default function build(dir: string, reactProductionProfiling: boolean | undefined, debugOutput: boolean | undefined, runLint: boolean | undefined, noMangling: boolean | undefined, appDirOnly: boolean | undefined, turboNextBuild: boolean | undefined, experimentalBuildMode: 'default' | 'compile' | 'generate'): Promise<void>;
export {};


Error Context:
The error seems to arise from the import of next/dist/build in server.ts:
import nextBuild from 'next/dist/build';

I've checked the next package, and while the next/dist/build module exists, it doesn’t seem to have a default export, causing this issue. Here's what I've tried:

Adding @ts-expect-error to silence TypeScript.
Confirming that all imports are correct in the index.d.ts.
Updating Next.js and dependencies to the latest version.

But the build process still fails with the same error. How can I resolve this, or is there a better way to handle Next.js build in a Payload + Next.js project?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Problem:
I encountered the following error when trying to build a Next.js + Payload CMS application using a custom express server in TypeScript:
Error: No default export found in imported module "next/dist/build". import/default

This occurred in my server.ts file, specifically when trying to import and use next/dist/build to build the Next.js application.
Solutions I tried (didnt work):
To resolve the error, I followed these steps:
1. Correct the nextBuild import:
The error was caused because the next/dist/build module does not have a default export, but I was trying to import it as if it did.
I changed the import in server.ts from:
import nextBuild from 'next/dist/build'; // This triggers the error

To:
import { build as nextBuild } from 'next/dist/build'; // Correct way to import

2. Ignore TypeScript errors temporarily:
Since TypeScript was throwing a compilation error even after fixing the import, I temporarily ignored the TypeScript error with @ts-expect-error for the specific line where I used nextBuild. This allows the code to compile while I work out a more permanent solution.
// @ts-expect-error Ignore the TypeScript error temporarily
await nextBuild(path.join(__dirname, '../'));

This silenced the TypeScript compiler rule violation for the time being, allowing the build to proceed.
3. Update index.d.ts:
If you are manually working with types and bundling, ensure your index.d.ts is properly defined to support the nextBuild function. The final index.d.ts should export nextBuild and build like this:
export { nextBuild, build };

But nothing seems to work, all of them were incorrect so i restored it to the code above.
The actual error image:
Vercel Deployment Error
